# Getting the values of the most recent clicks on an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a list of id's and when an id is clicked, I have some code that pulls the value of that id:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.show-editor', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var editPath = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  var jOption = $(this).text();
```

How could I do this, in jQuery, for every id clicked on since the user got to the page? Also, the page doesn't refresh, it uses jQuery and Json.

Comment: What do you mean every *id* clicked? Do you mean recording clicks on *all elements with an id attribute specified* ?

Comment: Secondly, there is nothing *id* related in your above code. The `.` selector is for selecting by class name.

Comment: Yes I know that. Every id has .show-editor as it's class. By id, I mean the id of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** Revised Answer, since I now understand the question ***

Depending on how long you want to keep them, your best bet seems like using sessionStorage.

Like so:

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    if(typeof sessionStorge["ids"] !== "undefined"){
        sessionStorage["ids"]=sessionStorage["ids"] + ', ' + this.id; 
       // be careful that all elements have an id (or that you don't mind undefined' all through your data)
      } else {
        sessionStorage['ids']=this.id;
      }
})
```

> Then To get all the data before the user leaves the page:

```
$(window).on('unload',function(e){
  var arr=sessionStorage['ids'] || '';
  arr=arr.split(',');
  // now you have an array of these ids to do with as you please
})
```

Comment: I want a list of the id's that have been clicked on by the user since they came to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var id;
$("*").click(function(){
    id= $(this).attr("id");
})
```